# how to find image style url from themed image

Tags: 7, theming, media

I've a code which theme & print the original image to specific image style.

```
print theme('image_style', array(
  'path' => $node->field_theme_image[$node->language][0]['uri'],
  'style_name' => 'home_theme',
));
```

I don't figure out how to get url of this new theme. I don't need to print the image but I need just url. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [`image_style_url`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/image_style_url/7) function instead of `theme`.

```
$path = image_style_url('home_theme', $node->field_theme_image[$node->language][0]['uri']);
```

Comment: This is not the correct way to do this.  See this article:  https://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/rendering-drupal-7-fields-right-way  also I have a way to do this without writing a single line of code.  See my answer below.